# List of mount points of external storage devices such as USB keyfobs and SATA external drives, from the cli

Tags: command-line, mount, external-hdd, sata, usb-device

I need to list all mount points associates to external storage devices such as USB keyfobs and SATA external drives.

The only way I found under Ubuntu, is to call 'mount' and grep for '/media'.  But I wonder if there is a better, more universal way.

All this from the command line interface (terminal/bash).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking in `/media` is a reasonable way to find *hotplug* block devices. You can also use `lsblk` to list the block devices and whether they are hotpluggable:

```
$ lsblk -l -p -o name,rm,hotplug,mountpoint
NAME      RM HOTPLUG MOUNTPOINT
/dev/sda   0       0 
/dev/sda1  0       0 /
/dev/sda2  0       0 [SWAP]
/dev/sda3  0       0 /home
/dev/sdc   0       1 
/dev/sdc1  0       1 
/dev/sdc2  0       1 
/dev/sdc3  0       1 /media/wd3
/dev/sdc4  0       1 
/dev/sdd   1       1 
/dev/sdd1  1       1 /media/clip
```

This shows that `/dev/sdc` is probably an external device (HOTPLUG=1), and that a partition is mounted on `/media/wd3`. Also there's another device on `/media/clip`. The `RM` column means removable, which sometimes applies to sd card readers, though in this case it is actually just a usb flash key.

You can also use `findmnt` to get from a directory name to the name of the device it is on:

```
$ findmnt -n -o source -T /media/wd3/my/sub/dir
/dev/sdc3
```

Comment: Darn, I get this on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Thar LTS:

`# lsblk -l -o name,rm,hotplug,mountpoint
lsblk: unknown column: hotplug,mountpoint`

Option -p is not available either.  `lsblk` is part of the _util-linux package_ and Ubuntu 14.04 comes with version _2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.7_.   For the moment, I hesitate selecting your answer, but I am tempted since in theory, it is exactly what I am looking for.

What OS are you using and more particularly, what version of `lsblk`?

Comment: @HansDeragon my lsblk is version 2.26.2, on fedora 22. I think it might be finding the hotplug info from `/sys` but it isn't obvious where as there is no pseudo file `hotplug` whereas there is a `/sys/block/sdd/removable` file which holds 1.

Comment: Accepted as a solution.  I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial Xerus, and it comes with _util-linux_ 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.  `lsblk` does the job.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between internal and external devices, so no, there's no better way than to hope mounting has been consistent enough that all external devices (and only those) are mounted under `/media`. But a user with the right permissions can easily mount e.g. an USB stick anywhere.

Comment: So this is how GUI file manager detect external devices?  By looking only under /media?  I ask because they seam to do a good job.

Comment: I guess nowadays they use DBus and the *org.freedesktop.UDisks.EnumerateDevices* method and/or listen to the *org.freedesktop.UDisks.DeviceAdded* signal.